# Laravel echo: channel authorization

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

From the [Broadcasting documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#authorizing-channels)

```
Broadcast::channel('order.{orderId}', function ($user, $orderId) {
    return $user->id === Order::findOrNew($orderId)->user_id;
});
```

> All authorization callbacks receive the currently authenticated user as their first argument and any additional wildcard parameters as their subsequent arguments. In this example, we are using the `{orderId}` placeholder to indicate that the "ID" portion of the channel name is a wildcard.

The sentence `All authorization callbacks receive the currently authenticated user as their first argument` is true for broadcasting on web, what if we build broadcasting for mobile application and  a user from a mobile application wants to subscribe to a channel? Then this `user` wont exist any more.

How can we authorize users coming from mobile application?

Comment: if users are required to authenticate, there's no difference between web or mobile or an API.

Comment: @AliAli Then what will be `$user` parameter? no session is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The protocol used in server and client must be the same. Despite of the fact Laravel Echo uses Socket.io, but installing Socket.io on android application wont work. I have to install [LaravelEchoAndroid](https://github.com/MrBin99/LaravelEchoAndroid) package on android and use Bearer token as authentication.

Hint: This package has a compile error and by changing maven it will work.